# Can I safely interpret ISO-8859-1 strings as Win1252 when parsing e-mail?

Tags: email, encoding, character-encoding

I need to support decoding ISO-8859-1 in my e-mail client. Specifically sometimes messages contain attaches that have filenames starting with "?iso-8859-1?".

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ISO-8859-1 is pretty much the same as Windows 1252. I already have good tested code for decoding Win1252. Can I just use it directly and expect no problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Windows-1252 codepage coincides with ISO-8859-1 in the code ranges 0x00 to 0x7F and 0xA0 to 0xFF, but not for the range 0x80 to 0x9F. Since ISO-8859-1 has no characters defined for the range 0x80 to 0x9F, this is not a problem. ISO-8859-1 is thus a subset of Windows-1252.